# Registering mouseclicks with ws_ex_transparent active c++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, transparent

How do I get my window to register mouseclicks even tho ws_ex_transparent is on?

```
HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_LAYERED| WS_EX_TRANSPARENT, szAppName, wcWndName,
    WS_VISIBLE | WS_POPUP, 255, 150, w, h,
    NULL, NULL, hThisInst, NULL);
```

The window is flagged to be layered and transparent, along with

```
SetWindowPos(hWnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN), GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN), SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
```

placing it "topmost" (infront) makes it work as an overlay, but sadly, it doesnt register mouseclicks at all.

```
case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    PostQuitMessage(0); //does it listen?
```

So my question is easy: How do I get my layered, topmost, transparent window to register me clicking the mouse?

any help would be, well, helpful. thanks

---

**The solution** turns out to be using a fairly standard hook feature, included in the windows header.

The keyboard hook looks a bit different than the mousehook, but since im after the mousehook, this is the solution im posting. (if u happen to look for [a keyboard hook](http://www.unknowncheats.me/forum/c-and-c/83707-setwindowshookex-example.html))

```
mousehook; //global declaration
LRESULT CALLBACK HookCallback(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT k = (PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)(lParam);
    if (wParam == WM_LBUTTONDOWN)
{
MessageBox(NULL, "LM is pressed", "key pressed", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
}
    if (wParam == WM_RBUTTONDOWN)
{
MessageBox(NULL, "RM is pressed", "key pressed", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
}
return CallNextHookEx(Mousehook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

and calling it in winmain (before msg)

```
Mousehook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, HookCallback, NULL, 0);
```

Comment: As well as the confusion over `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT`, if your window is actually 100% transparent (i.e. its alpha value is 0) then it won't see any mouse input anyway. You can give it an alpha value of 1 which results in it effectively being invisible but will register mouse input like a normal window.

Comment: Im currently able to draw a circle, but I want it to draw different stuff when I press the mousebutton. I dont know exactly what u mean by changing the alpha value, for what? the createwindow function? or my glclear()? without ws_ex_layered it becomes all black, wether or not i have ws_ex_transparent (to allow click-through)

Comment: So you're not using `SetLayeredWindowAttributes`? In that case you don't have a truly transparent window, you just have a window that doesn't paint anything.

Comment: im calling SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd, 0x0, 0, LWA_COLORKEY);
maybe i should post the source

edit: heres a pastebin for it http://pastebin.com/6AZ56fWZ
doesnt need fancy linking, only multibyte character set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you mixing `WS_EX_LAYARED` and `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` together, instead of using Layered Transparency?

In any case, see this article for some info about what `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` actually does:

[Like the cake, WS_EX_TRANSPARENT is a lie, or at least not the entire truth](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/12/17/10378525.aspx)

For what you are asking, you need to handle `WM_NCHITTEST` and have it return `HTCLIENT` instead of `HTTRANSPARENT` for any area that you want to be clickable on a transparent window.  However, `WM_NCHITTEST` does not work with `WS_EX_LAYERED`, so you will have to remove `WS_EX_LAYERED` and use `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` by itself, and then process `WM_ERASEBKGND` and have it return 1 without drawing anything to get the transparent effect.  Then you can use `WM_NCHITTEST`.

Comment: The window doesnt stay translucent without ws_ex_layered, and I need that to get my overlay working. stopping erasebgr doesnt leave the background clear to blend with, but black

Comment: Again, you should not be mixing `WS_EX_LAYERED` and `WS_EX_TRANPARENT` together. A translucent window is not fully transparent, so you should be able to click on it just fine, provided you are not clicking on an area that is 100% transparent. If you need to mix translucency and transparency together in the same window, use per-pixel alpha blending for that.

Comment: without ws_ex_layered i cant get it to be translucent, and without ws_ex_transparent it wont allow clicks through. Ideally this overlay would listen for mouseclicks, while still allowing them through.

i might be in over my head here hm, I wouldnt know how to go about achieving per-pixel alpha blending with winapi and opengl.

heres a pastebin if u feel like having a laugh 
http://pastebin.com/6AZ56fWZ

Comment: You cannot really have it both ways. Either you click on your overlay window itself, or you click-through to the window underneath it. You cannot click on the overlay, process the click, and then pass the click on to the next window. Clicks only go to one target window. For what you are attempting, you will have to use `WS_EX_LAYERED` for translucency, `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` for click-through, and a separate mouse hook to detect clicks so you can check if the mouse is within the bounds of your overlay window and not obscured by any window on top if it. Not an elegant solution, but it might work.

Comment: So I will need to make a mouse hook that reads clicks from the other window, and have my rendering change based on that input?

Comment: Not "steal" the clicks, just react to them. The clicks themselves will still go through to the next window. But the hook will tell you when the mouse is being clicked, and then you can grab the mouse coordinates and check if they are within your overlay's bounds, and if so then act "as if" the click was on the overlay itself rather than passed through.

Comment: Hm, guess ill have to add mousehooking to my repertoire somehow. thanks for the advice.

Comment: Look at [`SetWindowsHookEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990.aspx) or [`RegisterRawInputDevices()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645600.aspx) for the mouse hooking.  Since you already have a window (the overlay), you should use `RegisterRawInputDevices()`, that way the mouse will send [`WM_INPUT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645590.aspx) messages directly to your window with minimal overhead. This is preferred over using `SetWindowsHookEx()`, which is for lower-level hooking.

Comment: See the [Raw Input](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645536.aspx) API documentation for more details.

Comment: Just confirming that your solution was right. A standard mousehook does the trick, atleast this far. thanks :D